# Select parent and child records while search child record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have two tables 'Family' and 'FamilyLink'. If I search the 'Family',  I need the parent entries also.
**Family:**

```
Id  Name    Type
1   A       1
2   A1      2
3   AAA     3
4   B       1
5   B1      2
6   BBB     3
0   0       0
```

**FamilyLink:**

```
Id  parentId
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   0
5   4
6   5
```

If I search 'AAA' I want results like below

```
Id  Parent Id   Name
1:0  0          A
2:1  1:0        A1
3:2  2:1        AAA
```

If I search 'BBB' I want results like below

```
Id  Parent Id   Name
4:0  0          B
5:4  4:0        B1
6:5  5:4       BBB
```

If nothing in search the results shown like below:

```
Id   Parent Id  Name
1:0  0          A
2:1  1:0        A1
3:2  2:1        AAA
4:0  0          B
5:4  4:0        B1
6:5  5:4        BBB
```

I tried like below query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT F1.ID, FL1.PARENTID, F1.NAME 
        FROM FAMILY F1 INNER JOIN FAMILYLINK FL1 ON F1.ID= F1.ID 
        INNER JOIN FAMILY F2 ON F2.ID = FL1.PARENTID  
        INNER JOIN FAMILYLINK FL2 ON FL2.ID = F2.ID WHERE F1.NAME
        LIKE '%AAA%'
```

Sample table create:

```
Create table Family (Id int, Name varchar(50), Type int)
insert into family values (0, 'O', 0)
insert into family values (1, 'A', 1)
insert into family values (2, 'A1', 2)
insert into family values (3, 'AAA', 3)
insert into family values (4, 'B', 1)
insert into family values (5, 'B1', 2)
insert into family values (6, 'BBB', 3)


Create table FamilyLink (Id int, parentId int)
insert into FamilyLink values (1, 0)
insert into FamilyLink values (2, 1)
insert into FamilyLink values (3, 2)
insert into FamilyLink values (4, 0)
insert into FamilyLink values (5, 4)
insert into FamilyLink values (6, 5)
```

Not getting the expected result.
please help.

thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of data. You've supplied DDL and DML at the end, yes, but the images are huge, distracted, and I suspect will attract downvotes from those who open the question to see a wall of images. Use Markdown tables or tabular `text` if you want to displayu your *expected* results; they aren't needed at all for your sample data.

Comment: Also, please format your query so it can be read easily.

Comment: Are your sample data correctly from FamilyLink

Comment: @D-Shih, Sorry , Now I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the tables are a bit wierd?
If you want BBB's parent to be B1, shouldn't the parentid of id 6 in familylinks be 5 instead of 2? Because when I look at your sample tables it looks like BBB's parent is A1 (2)

If you switched the parent mapping you could do this:

```
Declare  @Family table (Id int, Name varchar(50), Type int)
Declare @FamilyLink table (Id int, parentId int)
declare @searchvalue varchar(50) = 'AAA'

insert into @Family values (0, 'O', 0)
insert into @Family values (1, 'A', 1)
insert into @Family values (2, 'A1', 2)
insert into @Family values (3, 'AAA', 3)
insert into @Family values (4, 'B', 1)
insert into @Family values (5, 'B1', 2)
insert into @Family values (6, 'BBB', 3)



insert into @FamilyLink values (1, 0)
insert into @FamilyLink values (2, 1)
insert into @FamilyLink values (3, 2)
insert into @FamilyLink values (4, 0)
insert into @FamilyLink values (5, 4)
insert into @FamilyLink values (6, 5)


;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT name, f.id, fl.parentId
  FROM @Family f
  JOIN @FamilyLink fl ON fl.id = f.Id
  WHERE Name = @searchvalue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.Name, f.id, fl.parentId
  FROM CTE
  JOIN @Family f ON f.id = cte.parentId
  JOIN @FamilyLink fl ON fl.id = f.Id
  WHERE f.Type > 0
)
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE
  Order by id
```

Comment: Wow great.   Thanks for your answer. It's possible with only select statements?

Comment: As long as you only have an x amount of parents, yes. But to handle a more dynamic amount of parents you'll have to create some kind of loop like the recursive CTE as above.

Comment: Yes, I have only 3 level parent. Could you please select statement without loop. Thanks